# Powerpoint: transparent UI for copying graphics (like tracing paper)

Tags: powerpoint, transparent

I Need to translate some graphical content into PowerPoint. I just imagined it would be really cool to make PowerPoint itself transparent, put the source Image "below" and then start copying the content with PowerPoint shapes. Like this:

[image]

Does such a Thing exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a shape, make it about 50% transparent, then right-click on it and choose **Format Shape**. Then under **Shape Options>Fill& Line**, set the Fill **Transparency** to about **50%**. Now right-click on the shape and choose **Set as Default Shape**.

Place the image to be replicated on the slide, then move it to the background. Draw transparent shapes on top. When you're all done, make the shapes opaque.

Comment: not what i am looking for, but certainly a feasible workaround